# Is OLAP/MDX a good way to process data w/ unknown values at various aggregation levels

Tags: mdx, hierarchical-data, olap, missing-data

I'm new to OLAP, so perhaps I don't know the right terminology to use for this question, but bear with me here.

I work with lots of hierarchical, multidimensional data where parent/aggregated cells mostly have data, but child/leaf cells are often missing data (attribute values are unknown but non-zero). I currently use a combination of scripting and SQL to work with it, but that's getting unwieldy. It seems like OLAP cubes and MDX are better suited to the *structure* of the data, but not necessarily to *tasks* I need to do with it. For example:

- OLAP seems mainly designed for read-only reporting; I do a lot of modifications to the data in batch processes
- OLAP seems to like having complete leaf-level data to calculate aggregates; my data has missing values at various levels

Examples of what I want to do:

- Load original multi-level data into cube and preserve known parents; don't overwrite or display their values as calculated aggregates of children (which may be incomplete).
- Create/update/delete cells in a cube based on results from complicated queries/joins of other cubes. Sometimes a cube needs to be transformed to use a slightly different dimension definition.
- Users require estimates for unknown values. I can create decent estimates, but need to adjust them so they conform to known parents/children across all dimensions and levels (this is much harder than it sounds). I am already doing this, but it involves pulling the data out of the RDBMS into a custom executable.
- Queries and calculations need to be able to handle the unknowns properly. Ideally be able to easily query how much of an aggregated cell's value is made up of estimated vs. known values, possibly compute confidence/error statistics, or check whether we can derive an exact value for an unknown when it has a known parent and all known siblings, etc.
- Data can be large... up to tens of millions of fact table rows. Performance needs to be decent for batch jobs (minutes are ok, hours not so much).

Could an OLAP server and MDX be a good tool for this type of work? Are there any other tools that would work well for manipulating hierarchical/multidimensional/gap-filled data?

Answer (score 1):

That's some needs for an OLAP system, interesting and challenging :-) :

*- Load original multi-level data into cube and preserve known parents; don't overwrite or display their values as calculated aggregates of children (which may be incomplete).*

You can change the way cubes aggregate values in a hierarchy. Doing this in one hierarchy is fine doing this using in multiple hierarchies might start to get complicated. It's worth checking twice if there is a mathematical 'unique' solution to the problem with multiple 'special' hierarchies.

*Create/update/delete cells in a cube based on results from complicated queries/joins of other cubes. Sometimes a cube needs to be transformed to use a slightly different dimension definition.*

Here you can use writeback ([MDX function Update cube](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Update%20Cube.html)), but I think it's a bit too simple for your needs. Implementation depend on the vendors. Pay attention creating cells can kill your memory as for large cubes you can quickly have millions of cells in a subcube.

What is the sparsity of your model ? -> number of cells with data / number of total cells

Some models have sparsities of 1e-30, here it's easy to explode if you're updating all cells ;-).

*Users require estimates for unknown values. I can create decent estimates, but need to adjust them so they conform to known parents/children across all dimensions and levels (this is much harder than it sounds). I am already doing this, but it involves pulling the data out of the RDBMS into a custom executable.*

This is looking complicated The issue here is the complexity of the algos, a possible solution using MDX language and how they match with the OLAP engige (fast enough). You're taking the risk it explodes, but have a look at [Scope function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms145989.aspx)

*Data can be large... up to tens of millions of fact table rows. Performance needs to be decent for batch jobs (minutes are ok, hours not so much).*

That should not be a real challenge..

To answer your question, I don't think so. We've a similar problem - on the genetical field - and we are going to solve the problem 'adding' a dedicated calculation module to our OLAP solution. It's an interesting on going project

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I suspected that OLAP/MDX would not be a good fit, but wanted to get feedback from an expert who has more experience with it.The sparsity of my data tends to be in the .10 to .3 range, so it is not very sparse. I think I might load some sample data into an OLAP system and try a few things, but I'm not too hopeful at this point. I would be interested to hear about your custom module for the similar data.